# ping with tcpflow and tcpdump

Tags: networking, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

When I use `tcpflow icmp` and ping I have no answer, but when I use `tcpdump icmp` aand ping I'm getting answer. Is something wrong with my tcpflow configuration or it should be like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use tcpflow icmp and ping I have no answer

Uh... How about this: tcpflow captures data from TCP connections and ICMP messages (e.g., pings & etc) are not part of TCP connections.

Comment: tcpflow can capture ony tcp? I've been told that it can capture icmp and udp too, is it true?

Comment: From the man page:  tcpflow is a program that captures data transmitted as part of TCP connections (flows), and stores the data...

Comment: ICMP is over IP (not TCP);  in any case, the (non)results you got match what I would expect. (I imagine tcpflow might be able to **capture** anything but its purpose is to extract the data payload of TCP connections.